# Topology Manager Error on upgrade to SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion

we are upgrading SDL Web from 8.1.1 to 8.5 but we are getting the error that "Server Could not be contacted" when upgrading the Topology Manager.Can anyone help where the issue is.

Comment: Any clue as to which server? The Topology Manager server, the CM, discovery?

Comment: Did you perhaps bind the CM or Topology Manager site to a specific hostname?

Comment: Hi All, The issue is resolved now. Tis was due to our old CM server has hostname different when installed Content Manager,later the hostname changes and we are trying to upgrade the CM and Topology Manager with new hostname. Issue resolved after changing the hostname in Topology Manager Environment variable.

Comment: @mounika -  Good to know your issue has been resolved, please self answer to close this ticket.